# Menu Creation in SSRS

Tags: sql-server

I am created one report service in that 5 different report is there,means report1,report2,report3,report4,report5.So I need to create a menu for these report,means its look like one menu,if I click report1 I need report1 details like that..I am very new in this field so please help me as simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Often SSRS reports are wrapped up within a small app (often created with c# / vb.net) to provide additional security and navigation options.  With a simple web page, you will be able create you report menu, style it accoridngly and use Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms to trigger displaying the report